# How can I change the order of the BoxLayout in kivy?

Tags: python, layout, python-2.7, boxlayout, kivy

I am testing kivy and I want to create a BoxLayout so to stack some buttons. My problem is that the children that are added to the layout follow a bottom-top logic while I want the opposite. Do you know how can I reverse the order? Thanks!

Comment: what is your objective? why is the default bottom-top layout logic problematic for you? maybe you can simply logically reverse the order of your components (if kivy doesn't occlude some components the wrong way)

Comment: Imagine that you have a menu with three buttons (New, Load, Options). The usual thing is that the menu will show in a top to botton logic and not a bottom to top. The thing now in kivy is that when I use the boxlayout the "New" button will be at the bottom and on top that of the "Load " button sits and so on. The layout fills whith the buttons from the bottom and not from the top.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to do this.  Either pass your buttons to the add_widget() method in reverse order or if you're using Kivy >= 1.0.5, pass an index to add_widget

```
box = BoxLayout(...)
btn = Button(...)
box.add_widget(btn, len(box.children))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky way to do that.

**Use a gridlayout and set cols to 1**